# How can I have Finder find a file for real? ( search all files )

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur

I open up finder and use `command shift g` to go to the root directory `/`.

I type in the search bar in the upper right hand corner `mongod.conf` but Finder does not find it.

I verified the file is at:

`/user/local/etc`

using the shell.

Why can't it find it?  I need to be a able to search all files on the machine.

I am running Big Sur 11.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For "Search:" choose "This Mac"
- Click the "+" button
- In the drop-down choose "System files" and "are included"
- (optionally, also include hidden files with: "File visibility" and "Visible or Invisible")

If the the options for System files and File visibility are missing, you can check them by selecting "Other..." in the drop-down menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... never noticed that + button and would not have known what to search for ... I had to select `other` and then type in `system files` and `visibility` ...

Comment: Is there a way to save these settings so I don't have to set them every time?

Comment: Yes, with the "Save" button :-)